# How to wait for one task to finish before calling another without blocking?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Trying to do something like this:

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginWrite, stream.EndWrite, task1Data, 0, task1Data.Length, null, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

Task task2 = Task.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginWrite, stream.EndWrite, task2Data, 0, task2Data.Length, null, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
```

But correct me if I'm wrong but isn't there a chance task2 could execute while or before task1 executes? I want something like ContinueWith where the code doesn't block but task2 still does not execute until task1 completes.

I tried doing `Task task2 = new Task(...)` so I could call `task1.ContinueWith(task2);` but it wouldn't compile. I'm pretty sure I have to use FromAsync (which runs automatically). I think putting `task1.Wait();` between the two lines would work but wouldn't that block? Trying to stay away from blocking..

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
task1.ContinueWith(t=>Task.Factory.FromAsync(stream.BeginWrite, stream.EndWrite, task2Data, 0, task2Data.Length, null, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent));
```

Comment: That'll do it. How could I forget lambdas. Thanks!